# Stuck in jquery with checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have three textboxes and a few checkboxes. I want when I select first checkbox then it displays in the first textbox and when I select second checkbox, it displays in second textbox and the same for the third checkbox. I have written this jquery but it is not working well Please help someone:-
My HTML code for textbox is:-

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <!-- <h4><strong>REDEEM YOUR GIFT/GIFT VOUCHER</strong></h4>
  <h5><em>Kindly fill-in your Promotional Code and Coupon No. in the boxes below.</em></h5> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="text" class="form-control wizard-required" id="selectedtext" name="selectedtext">
    <label for="voucher-code" class="wizard-form-text-label">Option 1*</label>
    <div class="wizard-form-error"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my HTML code for checkboxes is:-

```
<div class="wizard-form-radio">
  <input name="check_list[]" class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="Bangkok">
  <label for="Bangkok">Bangkok</label>
</div>
<div class="wizard-form-radio">
  <input name="check_list[]" class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="Pattaya">
  <label for="Pattaya">Pattaya</label>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery:-

```
$('.chkbx').click(function(){
  var text = "";
  $('.chkbx:checked').each(function(){
    text+=$(this).val() + ',';
  });
  text=text.substring(0,text.length-1);
  $('#selectedtext').val(text);
  var text1 = "";
  $('.chkbx:checked').each(function(){
    text1+=$(this).val() + ',';
  });

  text1=text1.substring(0,text1.length-1);
  $('#selectedtext1').val(text1);
```

Here selectedtext is the id of first textbox and selectedtext1 is the id of second textbox.

Comment: Hi, post your html code

Comment: <input required type="text" class="form-control wizard-required" id="selectedtext" name="selectedtext"> <input required type="text" class="form-control wizard-required" id="selectedtext1" name="selectedtext1"> <div class="wizard-form-radio">
         <input name="check_list[]" class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="Bangkok"><label for="Bangkok">Bangkok</label></div>

Comment: Hi @user3331039, post your all html code in stackoverflow only

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with solution

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  var val = ($(this).prop("checked")) ? $(this).val() : "";
  var textboxKey=$(this).attr("textboxKey");
  
  $("#" + textboxKey).val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required type="text" class="form-control wizard-required" id="selectedtext" name="selectedtext">
<input required type="text" class="form-control wizard-required" id="selectedtext1" name="selectedtext1"> 
<div class="wizard-form-radio">
  <input name="check_list[]" class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="Bangkok" textboxKey="selectedtext">
  <label for="Bangkok">Bangkok</label>
</div>
<div class="wizard-form-radio">
  <input name="check_list[]" class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="Singapore" textboxKey="selectedtext1">
  <label for="Singapore">Singapore</label>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

I have used a user defined attribute **textboxKey** in checkbox just to create a mapping between checkbox and textbox. **textboxKey** contains the input text `id` which will help to insert the data to textbox.

Comment: I want this dynamically because I have so many checkboxes. I want when the user selects the first checkbox from like 100 of checkboxes, then it displays one first textbox, then select any of the 2nd checkboxes, it displays in the second textbox.

Comment: @user3331039 Are you looking for https://jsfiddle.net/rpftacb4/